# Access the ESM module scope from function body

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Before ESM, I could access the `module` variable.

I explicitly don't want to do this:

```
const bar = 1

export function foo() {

  bar

}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
export function foo() {

  module.bar = 1

}
```

Is `global` my only option?

---

EDIT: It just occurred to me I could use the function binding. This could serve a similar function to the module scope.

```
export async function foo() {

  foo.bar = 1

}
```

---

EDIT: Actually, this will cause problems if it's async.

---

### Use case

As many have asked, the complete use case is here:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/447190/projectional-javascript-editor-while-maintaining-compatibility-with-plain-text-e

Comment: "*I explicitly don't want to do this*" - why? What do you think is wrong with that?

Comment: "*I want to do something like*" - are you looking for a different behaviour? Are you just looking for an unconventional syntax, but want to achieve the exact same thing as a module-scoped constant would?

Comment: what is the actual use case here? from what i see, your first formulation seems fine..

Comment: I want everything to be scoped within functions so they can be easily moved around, and are self-contained. I plan on moving each function to its own file, and if two functions depend on a module scope, then they can't be in their own file without refactoring. Does that make sense?

Comment: @vaughan If two functions in two different files depend on something shared, it won't help anything to put that shared something inside each (?!) function. It seems you are asking for the impossible there. But actually a module-scoped variable is still the proper solution: you can `export` it and then `import` it in the modules that define the functions.

Comment: @vaughan If you want to put every single function in its own file anyway, I don't get why you think that the functions need to be easy to move around?

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand what to suggest when you don't really describe the actual problem you're trying to solve.  Where do you want this variable accessible from?  Where do you NOT want it accessible from?   What is the problem with your  first code block because that's how you declare variables that are accessible from anywhere in this module and who's value lasts beyond one function invocation, but are not directly accessible from outside the module.  Please define your problem statement.

Comment: @jfriend00 The complete use case is here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/447190/projectional-javascript-editor-while-maintaining-compatibility-with-plain-text-e. It's rather complex which is why I scoped the question on SO precisely.

Comment: That use case is rather complex, but I think it's required to understand it in order to have any idea how to answer this question. I did not really follow what you're trying to do, but it seems like you just need a way (probably using your inserted tags) to associate one or more module-level variable declarations with a particular function. Note, you could use a class definition with static properties and static functions as that is one way to associate static variables with functions. But, this doesn't give you privacy for the statics (like module-level variables do) when exporting the class.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. A scope is not an object (with the exception of the global object backing the global scope).

Do not try to mix up the concepts. If you want a variable, declare a variable! This will make things easier for you and for everyone else who will work with that code.

Comment: IMHO this thinking of mixing scope and binding is caused by Java which calls it's binding "scope". Java can get away with it because they don't have functions and therefore don't have a traditional stack-based scope mechanism. It has polluted the minds of generations of programmers. I grew up learning programming in C/C++ so had a separate understanding of scope and binding.

Comment: @slebetman Are you saying I should have written "binding" instead of "scope"? I guess neither is really accurate, I was referring to the *lexical environment* in spec terms. Either way, my point is that this "thing that holds the variables" is not a JS object, and cannot be accessed as one.

Comment: No, I'm just lamenting on the OP's mixup between scope and object binding. It's unfortunate because understanding scope is central to understanding closures.

Comment: @slebetman Thanks, updated the text in the question.